# TestNG [Error] Cannot instantiate class if testng.xml having more than 6 classes (in command prompt)

Tags: ant, selenium, webdriver, testng

As per my project, having 15 classes in testng.xml. When i run testng, i got OutofMemory exp.. so i given more heap memory (in eclipse) then its working fine.

I added build.xml file to my project and when i try to run through command prompt, getting :TestNG [Error] Cannot instantiate class (for 7th class).
Upto 6 classes its working fine.

I tried by allocating memory max 1548m to jvm in command prompt but no use. There is no Xmx option in ant bat file just like eclipse.

Comment: If your actual question is how to increase the memory available to ant, I would straight away ask for that. Would make your question much more specific and more straight to the point.

Comment: Hi Hakre, Thanks for your comment. My problem is... i am facing Cannot instantiate class if there are more than 6 classes in testng.xml using Ant through command prompt. I am not sure that it is because of memory.. but i tried to allocate more memory as said above but no use. i request to figure out this issue..

Comment: Try ant with `-v` or eventually `-d` switches. See if it spreads more light on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message carefully and find out which class TestNG can't instantiate. Most likely, that class doesn't have a public, parameterless constructor. This has nothing to do with the number of classes in your `testng.xml`.

Comment: Thanks Cedric Beust, all classes are declared rightly. exp: if error is displayig for 6th one, if i deleted two of classes before it, then error is displaying for new class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you profile your test , Most of the times for lager suits memory cleaning is a important. Use some tool like jprofiler and see whether there are any memory leaks in your tests.

Comment: Thanks Dharshana, As of now, i didnt used any tools like jprofile to check memory leaks. surely i will check that...